# Hi, I am extremely new to C++ and I am doing a very simple project for school that just makes

Tags: c++

I am doing a very simple project for school that just makes this appear when typing in `3.14`:

```
****************HAPPY PI DAY**********************
```

I am getting a bunch of errors that I do not understand, including:

```
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\PiDay.cpp(13) : error C2065: 'If' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\PiDay.cpp(15) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cout'
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\PiDay.cpp(17) : error C2181: illegal else without matching if
```

Here is the code:

```
/* Written by ****** *****
on 2/19/14 */

#include <iostream.h>

int main() {
    double Number;
    cout << "--Pi Day Project--\n";
    cout << "Enter the value of pi to the nearest hundreth:";
    cin >> Number;
    If (Number != 3.14);
        cout << "That is incorrect";
        cout << "Please guess again: ";
        cin >> Number;
    else
        cout << "***************************** HAPPY PI DAY *****************************";
    return (0);
}
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: You need to review basic syntax. Check out this and see if you the errors make more sense: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson2.html

Comment: What does the first error seem to say about line 14?  Note also that you don't want a semicolon right after the `if` statement, but the three following lines need to be enclosed in braces `{` `}`.

Comment: -1 for the title alone!!

Comment: Thank you to everyone, problem solved, sorry to bother you with my beginner problems.

Comment: @user3334794 _'solved'_ isn't a better title either way! Accept an answer if it solved the problem for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Keyword `if`shall be written in lower case.
After if statement you placed a semicolon
Statements after if and before else you did not enclosed in braces.

Try the following code.

```
/* Written by ****** *****
on 2/19/14 */

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double Number;

    cout << "--Pi Day Project--\n";

    cout << "Enter the value of pi to the nearest hundreth:";

    do
    {
       cin >> Number;

       if ( Number != 3.14 )
       {
           cout << "That is incorrect";
           cout << "Please guess again: ";
       }
   } while ( Number != 3.14 );

   cout << "***************************** HAPPY PI DAY *****************************";

   return (0);
}
```

Comment: OT for this answer (didn't downvote) | Vlad, as an open word from my side: Your answers are very often just fixing the plain errors in code, with very little explanation coming along. For my taste your answers tend to miss the real reasons for problems and to point out misconceptions of the OP's. Please just overthink this critique without any bias against me, and what it could mean to improve the quality of your answers.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Sometimes it si simpler to write code than to explain why the original code is bad because the original code can contain many errors and has a bad style.

Comment: I mentioned, this note wasn't particularly meant for this answer of yours ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's called repwhoring

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at your errors one by one and try to figure them out, first:

```
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\PiDay.cpp(14) : error C2065: 'If' : undeclared identifier
```

C++ is case sensitive, and it doesn't like your `If`. Change it to `if` (lowercase).

```
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\PiDay.cpp(15) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cout'
```

This is complaining about line 15 because line 14 is wrong. An `if` doesn't have a `;` at then end, it has open brackets `{` which starts the `if` block.

```
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\PiDay.cpp(18) : error C2181: illegal else without matching if
```

Your `else` needs the brackets as well. It needs to close the last `if` block with `}` and open the `else` block with `{`. In the end you should have this:

```
if (Number != 3.14) {
    cout << "That is incorrect";
    cout << "Please guess again: ";
    cin >> Number;
} else {
    cout << "***************************** HAPPY PI DAY *****************************";
}
```

If you have programed in python before (my guess from the looks of your code) you need to know that white-space isn't important in C++, all block structures are set aside with curly brackets `{` and `}`.

Comment: Thank you all so much, sorry to bother you with my beginner problems.

Answer (score 0):

Replace (numbersign) with # and it should work fine. I would also replace If with if.

Answer (score -1):

There are some serious syntax errors here. I recommend that you go over the syntax of some the basics of the language. 'If' - 'I' must be lower case. All keywords lowercase. The block following the if must be enclosed in '{' '}'. Good luck!

Comment: This should be a comment!

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  Is it you who down voted all posts?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow No, downvoted the question only. Up-/Down-voted none of the answers here. Why it's that you're asking?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Because in my opinion it is necessary to comment your decision why you downvoted some post. Otherwise it is not clear for everybody.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Which I clearly did for the question (twice!). So what's your point?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ It is no matter. It is interesting to know the reason.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Downvotes are anonymous.

Answer (score -1):

The if in an if statement needs to be lowercase.  (Note that the first error complains about not knowing what 'If' means, and the third error complains about having an 'else' without a matching 'if'.)

One good debugging technique is to look at the first error (earliest line # it complains about) and start looking for problems there.

Comment: This should be a comment!